# Highcharts yAxis.max manage tick intervals dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set the max and min of y value dynamically based on the data but it is having some troubles for some values. I think the highchart couldn't set values that doesn't have a proper tick.

For eg: min: 3 and max 10. Then, the highchart won't set these values instead of that it will set a value ranging from 0...14. This is just an example value, sometimes I get 36000.14 as min and 454533.18 as max.

So my logic isn't working in that case.
This is the part of code which I currently have:

```
data = [3.43, 3.58, 4.86, 8.55, 8.77, 4.44, 9.67]
```

```
maximum_val = Math.ceil(maximum_val) eg: 10
minimum_val = Math.floor(minimum_val) eg: 3
evolution_options.yAxis[$('#div_count_'+div).find('#y_axis_lbl').text()] = {
  min: minimum_val,
  max: maximum_val,
  title: false,
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: 'black'
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e3fy1vu9/

**Further Brainstorming**

I think it is because the min value isn't a multiple of the max value so Highchart couldn't calculate how to split the tick. If there was any way so I could set the max value as the multiple of the min value.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with the sample data to which one you want to set the yAxis min and max?

Comment: Updated with fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here is my advice how to calculate the max and min for yAxis from the defined data.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qwt1kx7/

```
  yAxis: {
    min: Math.floor(Math.min(...data)),
    max: Math.round(Math.max(...data)),
    tickAmount: Math.round(Math.max(...data)) - Math.floor(Math.min(...data)) + 1 //1 count the min or max as itself
  },
```

Please test it and let me know if it fits to your requirements. Because the **tickAmount** value depends on how many values is included in the data array and probably some modifications are needed for larger data.

EDIT:

Try to use this custom solution to calculate the yAxis positions:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ztaj6Lkd/

```
var positions = [],
    tickNumbers = 5,
    tick = Math.floor(Math.min(...data));

for(let i = 0; i < tickNumbers; i++) {
    positions.push((Math.round(tick * 100) / 100));
  tick += Math.round(Math.max(...data)) / tickNumbers
}
//add the max 
positions.push(Math.round(Math.max(...data)))
```

Comment: This would work for smaller values like I have mentioned in the sample data. But as I have mentioned I will also be getting values larger than that I want a universal tickAmount calculator. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Amal please test your data with those options: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rz8x04jh/

Comment: Sorry but it's not working for me. I have set the tickAmount but no luck so far.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I use two y axis with this data. I will get only 3 points in the resulted graph. 3 tickpositions only.

Comment: I think it is because the min value isn't a multiple of the max value so Highchart couldn't calculate how to split the tick. If there was any way so I could set the max value as the multiple of the min value.

Comment: Hi I managed to fix it by setting ```alignTicks:false```. Thanks for your help alot :).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have fixed it by setting this `alignTicks:false` option.

```
evolution_options.yAxis[$('#div_count_'+div).find('#y_axis_lbl').text()] = {
  min: minimum_val,
  max: maximum_val,
  title: false,
  labels: {
    style: {
      color: 'black'
    }
  },
  alignTicks: false
}
```